# Creating all possible ways of a boolean array of size n?

Tags: java, arrays, boolean, combinations

I need to be able to create a boolean array of one combination and run it through a program to see if it works. If not then I dispose of it and go to the next combination. My issue is that I don't know how to create this array because n can be equal anywhere from 1-1000. So I was planning on using Integer.toBinaryString but that won't work due to its too big when it gets to past 32.
Any help would be greatful.

Thanks!

Comment: what is n? The length of the array?

Comment: sorry my bad, n is the number of spots needed to be in the boolean array

Comment: Have you considered using an [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)? ArrayList<Boolean> for example allows you to add an indefinite number of booleans. It is like a self extending array.

Comment: My main issue is that I don't know how to create all possible combinations, such as for a size 3 the first combination would be 000, then the next would be 001, next 010 or something along that nature.

Comment: So... n is the number of digits in the boolean array, and you want to create an array of all boolean numbers up until n digits? Is that right? Have you considered using [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)?

Comment: n is the number of spots in the array. I need all the combinations of the array

Comment: Will [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) work for you? Try looking into it.

Comment: It might but I am not exactly sure how to implement it into my solution

Comment: You probably don't want to generate all of the combinations up front because there are 2^n of them (2^100 ~10^301 (10715086071862673209484250490600018105614048117055336074437503883703510511249361224931983788156958581275946729175531468251871452856923140435984577574698574803934567774824230985421074605062371141877954182153046474983581941267398767559165543946077062914571196477686542167660429831652624386837205668069376 to be precise))

Comment: Well I am a creating one combination, testing it to see if it works, then keeping it if it does and then testing the next one to see if it has a better outcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "*accepted answer*" states that

> Tested and this will work for high values of n, such as 10000 and so on.

But this is **incorrect**.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int n = 3;
    for (int i = 0; i < Math.pow(2, n); i++) {
        String bin = Integer.toBinaryString(i);
        while (bin.length() < n)
            bin = "0" + bin;
        char[] chars = bin.toCharArray();
        boolean[] boolArray = new boolean[n];
        for (int j = 0; j < chars.length; j++) {
            boolArray[j] = chars[j] == '0' ? true : false;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(boolArray));
    }
}
```

When `n > 31` it will loop forever repeating the first 2^31 combinations since `i` will *overflow* and will never reach `Math.pow(2, n)`. You can easily test this with

```
public static void main2(String[] args){
        int n = 32;
        for (int i = 0; i < Math.pow(2, n); i++){
            if (i == Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
                // i overflows
                System.out.println("i exceeded Integer.MAX_VALUE");
            }
        }
    }
```

Code above will indefinitely print `i exceeded Integer.MAX_VALUE`
However this can easily be corrected using `BigInteger` or a similar data structure for looping. The code below will work for `n <= Integer.MAX_VALUE`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int n = 32;
    BigInteger bi = BigInteger.ZERO;
    BigDecimal rows = new BigDecimal(Math.pow(2, n));
    while (bi.compareTo(rows.toBigInteger()) < 0) {
        String bin = bi.toString(2);//Integer.toBinaryString(i);
        while (bin.length() < n)
            bin = "0" + bin;
        char[] chars = bin.toCharArray();
        boolean[] boolArray = new boolean[n];
        for (int j = 0; j < chars.length; j++) {
            boolArray[j] = chars[j] == '0' ? true : false;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(boolArray));
        bi = bi.add(BigInteger.ONE);
    }
}
```

Comment: In case anybody is interested in a bit of extra performance (like I needed), I used this in the loop to shave about 40% of the time
```boolean[] boolArray = new boolean[n];
long mask = 1;
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    boolArray[j] = (i & mask) > 0;
    mask <<= 1;
}```

(Oh, do note that I used longs instead of ints or bigintegers, this means it will work for n <= 63, also the speed comparison was compared to the example using integers and strings, so there will be an even better speedup compared to the BigInteger version (but of course there will be the n limit in this case)

Answer (score 3):

I've found the answer to your problem on another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10923601/java-generator-of-trues-falses-combinations-by-giving-the-number-n), and I've adapted it for you:

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int n = 3;
        for (int i = 0; i < Math.pow(2, n); i++) {
            String bin = Integer.toBinaryString(i);
            while (bin.length() < n)
                bin = "0" + bin;
            char[] chars = bin.toCharArray();
            boolean[] boolArray = new boolean[n];
            for (int j = 0; j < chars.length; j++) {
                boolArray[j] = chars[j] == '0' ? true : false;
            }
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(boolArray));
        }
    }
}
```

Will produce:

```
[true, true, true]
[true, true, false]
[true, false, true]
[true, false, false]
[false, true, true]
[false, true, false]
[false, false, true]
[false, false, false]
```

Tested and this will work for high values of `n`, such as 10000 and so on.

Comment: See I saw that but wouldn't it cause issues since i have to go to 1000 different spots in the array so I would need something with 1000 bytes.

Comment: Yes, my bad. I'm actually getting `OutOfMemoryError`'s when I try higher numbers for `n`. In that case, you'd simply have to create 2^n arrays with a size of [n]. I've updated my answer.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < Math.pow(2, n); i++) ` when `n > 31` will loop forever as the integer `i` will overflow as `assertTrue(Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1 == Integer.MIN_VALUE)` See my answer for rectified implementation

Comment: I highly doubt you tested it with 10000, not only will this solution loop forever, but also 2^10000 is such a big number that I'm not sure if any computer ever counted towards that...

Answer (score 0):

I know that the there is a Java tag. I just want to add my swift code converted from Java to the answer.

```
    let SIZE = 4
    let max = (pow(2, SIZE) as NSDecimalNumber).intValue;
    for i in 0..<max {
        var bin = String(i, radix: 2)
        while (bin.count < SIZE){
            bin = "0" + bin
        }
        var boolArray = [Bool]();
        var count = 0
        for ch in bin {
            boolArray.append(ch == "0")
            count = count + 1
        }
        print(boolArray)
    }
```

Comment: Instead of using string, you can generate this directly: https://github.com/passbook/BinarySequencer