# Creating all possible ways of a boolean array of size n in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, boolean

I want to create a list of all possible booleans with a given length `n`, using Python 3.

```
# suppose n = 2
# the expected output should be
output = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]
```

In my real application, `n` is never larger than 10.

[A similar post is here but for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27007752/creating-all-possible-ways-of-a-boolean-array-of-size-n).

Could you please show me how to do it in Python 3? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good opportunity to leverage `itertools`:

```
def boolean_combinations(n):
    return [
        *itertools.product(
            *[range(2) for _ in range(n)]
    )]
```

Comment: I did not get correct results with your code. When `n=2`, I got [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1)]. It misses (1, 0).